# "this" value in template helper returns Window

Tags: meteor

I have the following helper

```js
Template.meetingRow.helpers({
  isOwner: () => {
    console.log(this);
    return Meteor.userId() === this.owner;
  }
});
```

which will log the Window object to the console.

The this object returns the correct object in Template.meetingRow.events, and uses the correct values in the template, but isn't correct in the helper. Am I misunderstanding something?

Here's how it's being instantiated in its parent template:

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  {{#each meetings}}
    {{ > meetingRow }}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in ES2015, arrow functions inherit the context of the surrounding function, rather than being given their own.  What this means is that Meteor can't bind a context to your helper function if it's defined this way.

Solution (in ES2015 style):

```
Template.meetingRow.helpers({
  isOwner() function {
    console.log(this);
    return Meteor.userId() === this.owner;
  }
});
```

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) under "Lexical this".

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it